# Plotting from Interpolation

Tags: plotting, interpolation, data

There is a list

{{5.667680905429296`, 4.978997738176498`}, {6.062672641119444`, 
  4.821312039084925`}, {6.463307024854181`, 
  4.616923216296398`}, {6.869389071217502`, 
  4.358024801663491`}, {7.280737790273085`, 
  4.0328205724875374`}, {7.697184816760531`, 
  3.6220668338026347`}, {8.118573184417112`, 
  3.090204786097973`}, {8.544756235833926`, 
  2.354492374103027`}, {8.97559665513716`, 
  1.045159976700232`}, {9.168625618559851`, 
  6.355895552341976`*^-16}, {9.291801857401657`, 
  6.34776334121662`*^-20}}

in the form {x,y}. I interpolate the list using Data=Interpolation[{x,y}]. I want to plot the interpolated function as the dependence y(x). How can it be done?

Answer (score 5):

Writing:

```
points = {{5.667680905429296, 4.978997738176498}, 
          {6.062672641119444, 4.821312039084925}, 
          {6.463307024854181, 4.616923216296398}, 
          {6.869389071217502, 4.358024801663491}, 
          {7.280737790273085, 4.0328205724875374}, 
          {7.697184816760531, 3.6220668338026347}, 
          {8.118573184417112, 3.090204786097973}, 
          {8.544756235833926, 2.354492374103027}, 
          {8.97559665513716, 1.045159976700232}, 
          {9.168625618559851, 6.355895552341976^-16}, 
          {9.291801857401657, 6.34776334121662^-20}};

f = Interpolation[points, InterpolationOrder -> 2];

Plot[f[x], {x, points[[1, 1]], points[[11, 1]]}, 
           Epilog -> Point[points], 
           AxesLabel -> {x, y}]
```

I get:

[image]

which is what you want.

Comment: Why is it not smooth?

Answer (score 1):

You might want to use `InterpolationOrder`

```
ListLinePlot[points, InterpolationOrder -> 2, Mesh -> Full]
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Here shows the resulting curves and  smoothness of the Interpolation with change in the degree of the polynomial from 0 to 5

```
Plot[Evaluate@Interpolation[points, InterpolationOrder -> #][x], {x, 
    points[[1, 1]], points[[11, 1]]}, Epilog -> Point[points], 
   AxesLabel -> {x, y}] & /@ {1, 2, 3, 4, 5}
```

Here are the results

[image]

Also, by taking a good look at the first derivative is a good indication of where in the independent variable x range may need further additional points to get a good quality interpolation.

```
   f = Interpolation[points]; {xmin, xmax} = 
 MinMax[points[[All, 1]]]; Plot[{f[x], f'[x]}, {x, xmin, xmax}, 
 AspectRatio -> 2, PlotLegends -> "Expressions"]
```

[image]

Comment: The yellow curve is the 1st derivative of the interpolation function, but I do not know how to correctly label this in WM

Comment: `f = Interpolation[points];

{xmin, xmax} = MinMax[points[[All, 1]]];

Plot[{f[x], f'[x]}, {x, xmin, xmax},
 PlotLegends -> "Expressions"]`

Comment: Thank you Bob.. but this just place the Interpolation function . I really need to use a custom label  ( f(x) and f'(x)  )

Comment: With the code that I posted the `PlotLegend` shows `f(x)` and `f'(x)`, Perhaps you need to `Clear[f]`.